# How can I permanently get large dates from getdate () to 90 days?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to keep the date of 90 days ago on a tabl by taking the date of the day.
Tablonun ismi: etl.PackageExecutionDuration
I want the records to be deleted for 90 days. Column name to be compared: created_time. It will be 23:59:59 at the time of 90 days before.
How can I do that?

I have done the following query but have a simpler way or shape?

```
DELETE etl.PackageExecutionDuration where created_time<   (select CONVERT(datetime,
  DATEADD(SECOND,-1,
  CONVERT(datetime,
  CONVERT(date, 
  CONVERT(datetime, 
  DATEADD(DAY, -89, GETDATE())))))))
```

Comment: what data type is `created_time`? Can you not just do `...where created_time < dateadd(day, -90, getdate())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE etl.PackageExecutionDuration where created_time<   (select CONVERT(datetime,
  DATEADD(SECOND,-1,
  CONVERT(datetime, 
  DATEADD(DAY, -11, GETDATE())))))
```

This True query

Answer (score 1):

simplify to:

```
where created_time <= cast(dateadd(day, -90, getdate()) as date)
```

Comment: It will be 23:59:59 at the time of 90 days before for example: 01:01:2017 23:59:59

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE etl.PackageExecutionDuration where created_time<   (select CONVERT(datetime,
  DATEADD(milisecond,-1,
  CONVERT(datetime,
  CONVERT(date, 
  CONVERT(datetime, 
  DATEADD(DAY, -89, GETDATE())))))))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @emre.  Some explanation, along with the code that you have provided will help not only the individual asking this question, but all of those who read this question in the future.

Comment: The first and last `convert(datetime`s seem unnecessary.

Comment: DELETE etl.PackageExecutionDuration where created_time<   (select CONVERT(datetime,
  DATEADD(SECOND,-1,
  CONVERT(datetime, 
  DATEADD(DAY, -11, GETDATE())))))